# How to send large files with Nodemailer?

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

I'm building a website where people can buy songs, and when they do, they get an email with the song in attachments

I'm using Nodemailer for that with that "attachments" option

```
attachments: [
   {
      filename: req.body.purchasedSongName,
      path: path.join(__dirname, `../uploads/prods/songs/${req.body.purchasedSong}`),
      contentType: 'audio/mpeg'
   }
]
```

The problem is that when the song is too large (25MB+ apparently) Gmail gives me an error:

> Error: Message failed: 552-5.2.3 Your message exceeded Google's message size limits.

What solutions do I have to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

Simple: Don't send the file via email.

Instead, just send a link from where your users can download the song. You could also implement a system where one download link is usable exactly once, or for a limited time.